# Translate this if statement in to regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I had to translate the following if statement in to a regex so we could use it on a whole string

```
if (buffer[i] < 32 && !(buffer[i] == '\t' || buffer[i] == '\r' || buffer[i] == '\n'))
    buffer[i] = ' ';
```

Which I did by doing this

```
return Regex.Replace(base.ReadLine(), "[\0-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F]", " ");
```

However I don't like the way it looks, is there a way in regex to do the same thing I did in the if statement? Basicly

```
[\0-\x1f]~[\t\r\b]
```

Where the `~` would go the thing that represents "exclude the following" (It does not have to be this exact syntax, I was just wondering if there is something like this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) - it talks about regex negations. I'm not sure if it can directly help you, but it's the best I've got.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the look of your regex, you could use something like `/(?![\t\r\n])[\x00-\x1F]/`. The first part, `(?![\t\r\n])`, says to fail if the next character matches `[\t\r\n]`, and then the second part `[\x00-\x1F]` says to match any character <= 0x1F.

Comment: That was the exact pattern I ended up using after reading @Ken Wayne VanderLinde link.

Answer (score 0):

To negate something, use [**^**\t\r\b]. You can also try [negative lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) but the former is simpler IMHO.

Comment: Yes, but [^\t\r\b] would match all characters except those 3, I only want it to match characters under the value 32 expect those 3.

Comment: @Scott, you need to use that in conjunction with your other expression. I feel though that you might be looking at a negative lookbehind solution here. Can you post your sample text so that I can try lil more?

Comment: Please look at the if statement in the first code block, it shows the exact rules you need to follow, however I already got the answer, it was `(?![\t\r\n])[\x00-\x1F]` using negative lookaheads

Comment: @Scott, yeah I noticed and that's the negative lookbehind based pattern.